# How to have a div in the center of the screen with 4 images inside and never lose proportions

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to have 4 images (resized, but in their native proportion) in a div, always in the center of the screen. I can resize the window, get it bigger or smaller, and always have my images in the center of it, just with a little margin. Like this

[image]

I had a similar result with this kind of solution:

```
.container {
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

img {
max-width:50%;
}
```

The main problem is the window height. When I resize the window on the y axes they are cutted out of the screen. Maybe I need for some javascript.

not working code: http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/MYaGgd

Comment: should work fine, show a demo which is not working...

Comment: Here is the example. http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/MYaGgd

As I wrote, when I resize the window on the y axes, the container is cutted on top and bottom.